# Mojang Account not Working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a Mojang account and I own Minecraft on it but cannot login to Minecraft using the Minecraft website, the Mojang website or the Minecraft launcher.
On the Mojang website I get the error "unknown email or password" and on the Minecraft website I get "Oops, unknown username or password. If you are logging in with a Mojang account make sure to use your e-mail address as username." I also can't login to tekkit using it either.

Comment: You probably should contact Mojang support.

Comment: I could connect, so it may not be a server issue. You may have messed up your password.

Answer (score 5):

There are two things that could fix this:

1. Try your Minecraft username **and** your email. One might work.
2. If neither your username nor your email works, try to reset your password.

If those don't work, contact [Mojang support](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new)

Comment: down voted this, because as i have already all these things

Comment: It's the correct answer though.  Assuming you've tried those steps already, then the logon issue may be an issue with Mojang's authentication server. (which isn't something a user can fix.)  If anything, the only other troubleshooting step to add to this is to type your username/password in plaintext (like in notepad) and copy/paste it over to make sure it's 100% correct. For all we know, your account might of been hijacked and it's password changed, but the only error code available states excately what's on the tin.